# How to read a (CSV) file without separators given

Tags: java, csv, file

I'm trying to read a text file with Java. I suppose that the reading process will be the same or at least similar to reading a CSV file. However, the data isn't separated with delimiters nor does it have a header. But I know in which position data is written (i.e. "name" can have 10 characters and is in character positions 1-10, "surname" can have 15 characters and occupies positions 11-26 and so on...)

The "name" field would be filled with 10 hyphens, if there's not data given.

How can I proceed with this type of file?

Fields:
[image]

One line from the file that has to be read:
[image]

First Company --------Frankfurt 08.04.2021examplemailaddress@company.com 123456789 Second Company….

Comment: Yes, the "name" field would be filled with 10 hyphens, if there's not data given. I posted a list with example fields and their character lengths. I also included an example line. Hope that my questions seems more clear now.

Comment: First Company                                                         --------Frankfurt                               08.04.2021examplemailaddress@company.com     123456789                               Second Company….

Comment: the spaces in the text don't get included unfortunately..

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments.

Comment: This is not a CSV file in any way, as there are no delimiters between fields. This is a "Fixed Width" text file. You could parse it out yourself by chopping each line into fixed-width chunks...but if you look around, you will likely find packages to manage fixed-width data files in every language.

Answer (score 1):

Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ParsFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("input.csv");
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            String company;
            String zip;
            String city;
            String date;
            String eMail;
            String phone;
            while (line != null) {
                company = line.substring(0, 70);
                zip = line.substring(70, 78);
                city = line.substring(78, 118);
                date = line.substring(118, 128);
                eMail = line.substring(128, 158);
                phone = line.substring(163, 203);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Replace *input.csv* with the actual path to your file.
- The above code simply splits each line in the file into fields according to the lengths and order of fields that you stated in your question.
- I don't know what you want to do with the fields after you parse the line, hence I don't do anything with the variables like `company` and `zip` after assigning them a value.
- Note that I ignored the *Free field*.

Comment: A single `readLine()` reads the entire file because the file doesn't seem to contain a newline character.